# Finding address of a C struct inside an ELF file compatible to ARM Architecture

Tags: c, arm, elf, abi

In my project I defined: (This is not the real code - for abstraction purpose)

```
typedef struct {
...
} my_struct;
```

In some C file I declared:

```
my_struct my_struct_inst;
```

And in other 2 C files I used that struct by declaring:

```
extern my_struct my_struct_inst;
```

and used it's contents.

I compiled that code to ARM with RVCT2.2 and trying to find the address of that structure:

1) When does memory being allocated to my_struct_inst? On compilation time? On run time?

2) In the disassembly I can see that in the `.FLASH_RAM` section (probably where this kind of data belongs) there is some reference like:
my_struct_inst % 0x190
I got it with IDA. What does it mean? (That that struct instance will start at offset 0x190 from the beginning of `.FLASH_RAM` section?)

3) How exactly the actual address (where the struct actually sitting in memory) is being accessed when I write `my_struct_inst.some_member`  (should I read some ABI documentation?)

Comment: Write some C that says, "&my_struct_inst", compile it to assembly and look at the code.

Comment: Do you mean to print the address of the instance in run time?

Comment: That's what I meant. I think that answers 3), but maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: `my_struct_inst % 0x190` means that `my_struct_inst` is 0x190 bytes in size, and its contents is not initialized.

Comment: Thank's @IgorSkochinsky- You mean that 0x190 bytes allocated to it in the compilation time as Jitesh answered? (so in the elf itself there are 0x190 bytes reserved for it? or is it just an enrty that says my_struct_inst has 0x190 bytes and if it will be used a memory will be allocated to it in run time?)

Answer (score 2):

The memory for your structure will be allocated at compilation time.

The address will be defined by your linker script. To see the address of the structure (assuming it is a global variable), you will need the generated ELF file (lets call it a.elf, for this example). Then just run:

```
arm-eabi-objdump -t a.elf | grep my_struct_inst
```

Objdump "-t" will list all global symbols with its address and the section it belongs too. You can replace the "objdump" by any cross-compiled objdump that you have.